# .Ajax, .text Input display function

Tags: php, html, css, ajax

```
var log = document.getElementById("log");


$(function(){
    $('textarea').keypress(function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13 && !e.shiftKey) {

            log.innerHTML += "Company<br>";

            e.preventDefault();
            var frm = this.form; // don't submit the form yet

            log.innerHTML += "<br>";

            $.ajax({
                url: $(frm).attr('action'), // remember to specify which attribute you want
                data: $(frm).serialize(),
                dataType: "json",
                success: function() { 

                    log.innerHTML += "Ajax complete (form should be submitted now)<br>";

                    // submit the form when the ajax request is complete
                    // frm.submit();
                }
            });
        }
    });

});

<form action="#">
    <textarea name="comment"></textarea>
</form>

<div id="log"></div>
```

I am trying to set up the script to where I can display the results within the input. Is there a way to display the results whatever the user puts in the textarea below?

```
log.innerHTML += "Company<br>";
```

.innerHTML seems to be acting like a basic paragraph of text. All I need is to be able to display a list of links that are going to be put in the input to save them. Is there a way I can use .text() for the textarea?

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**HTML:**

```
<form action="#">
    <textarea name="comment"></textarea>
</form>

<div id="log"></div>
```

**JS:**

```
$('textarea').on('focusout', function(){
  $('#log').text($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use `$("#log").text("").append($("textarea").val());`

Comment: .append seems to only display whatever is put inside the parenthesis. Is there a way to connect the text area the same way to display whatever the user enters in the text area?

Comment: Just updated my answer to get the result I believe you are trying to get. This will clear the text each time and append the new text. If you want it to just add on each time, you can remove the `text("")` function

Comment: Awesome, thank you! Thats what I wanted. I only have 1 more problem and I am done. $("#log").append($("textarea").val()); I'm using it like this. This code is doing what I want. 

I am going to be adding on each time, so how can I split up the entries with <p></p>?

Comment: So you want the text in the log in a <p> tag? Not sure I understand what you mean. The code is being called every time the user presses a key.

Comment: Yeah, right now its working good. But I just need the entries separated with paragraphs tags. Ur right!

Comment: Does `$("#log").text("").append("<p>"+$("textarea").val()+"</p>");` give you your desired results?

Comment: Ahh, shoot! The other example was achieving what I was trying to do better. I just needed each entry to be on a different paragraph line. The example u just posted below only allows one entry at a time.

Comment: What determines where one entry ends and the other begins?

Answer (score 0):

Im going to be submitting url links within the form and each link has to be on a different line. It looks weird with all of them jamd together. Sorry lol